# I have two very simple beginner questions for Python

Tags: python

```
import random
wordlist = {'Candy', 'Monkey'}
level = 0
while level == 0:
    number = random.randint(1, 2)
    if number == 1:
        print 'Candy'
        secword = 'Candy'
        level = 2
    elif number == 2:
        print 'Monkey'
        secword = 'Monkey'
        level = 2

for i in secword:
    print i
```

I have a couple of questions about the code I just randomly wrote (I'm a beginner)

1) How do I assign a word in a list to a variable?
ex. assign the word 'Candy' into a variable because I always get the error (List is not callable)

2) How do I assign the variable i (in the for loop) to a separate variable for each letter?

Thanks! Tell me if it's not specific enough.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: Also, look into `random.choice()`. This whole thing can be reduced to about 4 or 5 more Pythonic lines.

Comment: possibly one line (not regarding the import statement): `for c in list(random.choice(["Candy","Monkey"])): print c` :)

Comment: would I have to import random for    random.choice()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be pointed out that `wordlist` is not actually a list, but a set.  The difference is that a set does not allow duplicate values, whereas a list does.  A list is created using hard-brackets: `[]`, and a set is created using curly-brackets: `{}`.

This is important because you can't index a set.  In other words, you can't get an element using `wordlist[0]`.  It will give you a 'set does not support indexing' error.  So, before you try to get an element out of `wordlist`, make sure you actually declare it as a list:

```
wordlist = ['Candy', 'Monkey']
```

I'm not sure what you're asking in your second question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I found out how to do the second part myself. I should've properly learned the differences between lists and sets.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `List is not callable` because you are probably using small brackets `()`. If you use small brackets, and do wordlist(0), you actually make interpreter feel like `wordlist` is a method and `0` is it's argument.

```
s = worldlist[0]  # to assign "Candy" to s.
```